# Change the visibility property from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to hide the 'Delete' link if value in CUST_ORDER_ID = 'X' but I don't know how to set the visibility property to "False"

My asp.

```
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ROWID" SortExpression="ROWID" Visible="False">         </asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CUST_ORDER_ID" HeaderText="ORDER ID"     SortExpression="CUST_ORDER_ID">
<ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
```

and the code behind

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'check is row non order type and allow user to delete
        Dim oid As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(2)
        If oid.Text = "X" Then
            Dim tb As Button = e.Row.Cells(1).Controls(1)
            'Dim tb = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteButton")
            tb.Visible = "False"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you might want to add an *asp/asp.net* tag to your *asp* question to attract *asp* attention

Comment: @Plutonix just did for him.

Comment: Why can't you add Visible property on your HTML?

Comment: Visible property is a Boolean not a String...  Change this `tb.Visible = "False"` ***to*** `tb.Visible = False`

Comment: Dim tb As Button = e.Row.Cells(1).Controls(1) throws this error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Dim tb = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteButton") throws this error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the ideas. This is the cleanest solution I found on this site but it was in c# so converted to vb.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and the code behind

```
Dim oid As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(2)
Dim tb = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteButton")
If oid.Text = "X" Then
    tb.Visible = True
Else
    tb.Visible = False
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can change to Templatefield

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col1">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:label ID="lbl1" runat="server" text='<%#left(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field1"),20)%>'>
     </asp:label>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

With this code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
Dim lbl1 As Label
   If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    lbl1 = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lbl1"), Label)
    If oid.Text = "X" Then
       lbl1 .Visible = "False"
    End If
   End If
End Sub
```

You can  use almost any control in template.